# D3 Grouped Bar Chart - Selecting entire group?

Tags: d3.js

I have a grouped bar chart similar to https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051
I used a mouseover function to fade the bars the mouse is currently not over

```
function mouseover(bar)
{
   d3.selectAll(".bar")
     .filter(function(d){ return (d != bar);})
     .transition(t)
        .style("opacity", 0.5);
}
```

While this works nicely to highlight a single bar, I now need to highlight the entire group / fade everything but this group.
So far I haven't been able to figure out though how to get from the datum element `d` passed via `.on("mouseover", function(d) ...` back to the entire group this element belongs to.
Is there a simple way to achieve this in D3v4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3 4.0 the [callback function for the `.on()` method is passed 3 arguments](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#handling-events): the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes).

Within the mouseover callback, you can `selectAll("rect")`, and filter out items which are in the current group (`node`). With this selection, you then set opacity to 0.5. On mouseout, you just need to set all opacity back to 1.0.  The pertinent code is:

```
 ...
   .on('mouseover', function(d, i, node) {
    d3.selectAll("rect")
      .filter(function (x) { return !isInArray(this, node)})
      .attr('opacity', 0.5);
   }
  )
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    d3.selectAll("rect").attr('opacity', 1.0);
    });
```

with a small helper function to check if a value is present in an array (array of DOM elements in our case):

```
 function isInArray(value, array) {
     return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
 }
```

The full code in context (given your linked example):

```
g.append("g")
 .selectAll("g")
 .data(data)
 .enter().append("g")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; })
 .selectAll("rect")
 .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
 .enter().append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
   .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
   .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
   .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
   .on('mouseover', function(d, i, node) {
    d3.selectAll("rect")
      .filter(function (x) { return !isInArray(this, node)})
      .attr('opacity', 0.5);
   }
  )
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    d3.selectAll("rect").attr('opacity', 1.0);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be:

Make a function which selects all group and gives it a transition of opacity 0.

The DOM on which mouse is over give opacity 1.

```
  function hoverIn(){
    d3.selectAll(".group-me").transition()
        .style("opacity", 0.01);//all groups given opacity 0
    d3.select(this).transition()
        .style("opacity", 1);//give opacity 1 to group on which it hovers.
  }
```

Make a function which selects all group and gives it a transition of opacity 1, when the mouse is out.

```
  function hoverOut(){
    d3.selectAll(".group-me").transition()
        .style("opacity", 1);
  }
```

On the group add a class and add the mouse out and in function like

```
  g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .classed("group-me", true)//add a class for selection.
    .on("mouseover", hoverIn)
    .on("mouseout", hoverOut)
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NjerWL96u2nJxGuWE8zA?p=info)