# d3 grouped bar chart highlight group on mouseover

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, highlight, grouped-collection-select

Solved: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/63rxjhs0/2/)

Issue #1: Have a grouped bar chart. I'd like the group to highlight if any bars in the group are moused-over.

Currently on mouseover sets all rects with class 'bar' to opacity 0.5 and then the specific rect to opacity 1. But how can I set the node or group of bars to opacity 1, so that they are highlighted against the others?

```
.on("mouseover", function(d, i, node) { //this is repeated should be in a function
        d3.selectAll(".bar").transition()
          .style("opacity", 0.3); //all groups given opacity 0
        d3.select(this).transition()
          .style("opacity", 1); //give opacity 1 to group on which it hovers.
        return tooltip
          .style("visibility", "visible")
          .html("<span style=font-size:30px;> " + "name:" + d.name +
            "</span>"
          )
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        d3.selectAll(".bar").transition()
          .style("opacity", 1);
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
      })
```

Issue #2: Also I would like the bar's x axis labels to behave similarly. So that the names of all but the current bar would have opacity 0.5

I did try adding a clas of bar to the xAxis text, but doesn't work,

```
.call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("font", "20px times")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", ".15em")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");
```

I this try implementing ideas from this post

[D3 Grouped Bar Chart - Selecting entire group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339628/d3-grouped-bar-chart-selecting-entire-group)

but I haven't been able to get it to work.

My attempt to give a class of d.name + index to each bar in a group. But I can't select then, the return "." + d.name isn't working as I'd expect.

```
      .attr("class", function(d, i) {
       return d.name.replace(/\s/g, '') + i + " bar"
      })
      .on("mouseover", function(d, i, node) { 
        d3.selectAll(".bar").transition()
          .style("opacity", 0.3); 
        d3.selectAll("." + d.name.replace(/\s/g) + i)
          .transition()
          .style("opacity", 1); 
        return tooltip
          .style("visibility", "visible")
          .html("<span style=font-size:30px;> " + "name:" + d.name +
            "</span>");
      })
```

The select should be,

```
d3.selectAll("." + d.name.replace(/\s/g, '') + i)
```

Actually each bar in each group could just be given a class of "group + index". There is no need for the regular expression.

Except for the text on the xAxis the highlighting is now working fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/63rxjhs0/8/)

```
.on("mouseover", function(d, i, node) {
        d3.selectAll(".bar").transition()
          .style("opacity", 0.3);
        d3.selectAll(".xAxisText").transition()
          .style("fill", "lightgray")
          .style("font-weight", "100"); //all groups given opacity 0
        d3.selectAll(".groupText" + i)
          .transition()
          .style("font-weight", "900")
          .style("fill", "black"); //give opacity 1 to group on which it hovers.
        d3.selectAll(".group" + i)
          .transition()
          .style("opacity", 1);
        return tooltip
          .style("visibility", "visible")
          .html("<span style=font-size:30px;> " + "name: " + d.name +
            " (on blue bar)</span>");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        d3.selectAll(".bar").transition()
          .style("opacity", 1);
        d3.selectAll(".xAxisText").transition()
          .style("fill", "black")
          .style("font-weight", "normal");
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
      })
```

Answer (score 2):

you could base the opacity for all bars on its .name value (which is common attribute per group in your example), eg

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) { 
    let selectedName = d.name;
    d3.selectAll(".bar")
      .style("opacity", function(d) {
        return d.name == selectedName ? 1 : 0.3;
      })

    //etc
```

Comment: Yes I was just thinking if that thanks. But of course there is the unlikely possibility of two people having the same name and the name actually comes as a first and second name and so two classes and more change people clash on second names.

Comment: Maybe a combination of first and second name trimmed with id concatenated. So that john murphy could become johnmurphy16 for index 16. I think that will be unique for each bar always.

Comment: I can add a class of name with white space removed and index concatenated like this .attr("class", function(d, i) {
        return d.name.replace(/\s/g, '') + i + " bar"
      })

Comment: Actually each bar in each group could just be given a class of "group + index". There is no need for the regular expression.